Is There an Apex Equivalent to a Flow Scheduled Path?
We have a Case follow-up process defined in a Flow as a Scheduled Path.
Is it possible to implement the same functionality in Apex?
Under the hood, is the Scheduled Flow Path implemented as a CronTrigger/CronJobDetail?

By the way, updated the answer based on some more research.

The only options we have in Apex are Scheduled Jobs (System.schedule) and Scheduled Batch Jobs (System.scheduleBatch). Unfortunately, this mechanism is limited to just 100 scheduled jobs. In other words, there isn't a directly  comparable feature in Apex. As far as "under the hood," Scheduled Paths are similar to Time-Based Workflow Actions. , although I believe they work from different queues (it's not explained at a technical level?). Time-Based Workflow Actions predate Apex, and they've never introduced a method for queueing these kind of actions in Apex. Both Scheduled Paths and Workflow Time Actions are placed into the WorkflowTimeQueue object (key prefix 055).

Since you mention scheduled batches, where scheduling is via specification of a delay, it makes sense to mention queueables with a delay.

Thank you Phil.  Unfortunately the max delay is not enough for our needs.

@sfdcfox, Thank you for the updated answer.  We're going to stick with Flow/Scheduled Path for now.  It doesn't always work, and we have no idea why, but it's simple to implement.  FYI, we are trying to rationalize what's happening on Case DML operations.  We had/have Work Flow Rules, Process Builder Flows, and Flows.  We are moving everything we can to the Case Trigger Handler.
